# MongoDB Set Field with Wildcards

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a wildcard in the middle of the field hierarchy for $set

currently I'm using:

```
db.collection.update({name: /^test$/i}, {$set:{"stats.Human.BattackPlvl": 4}});
```

I'm curious if i can do something like this:

```
db.collection.update({name: /^test$/i}, {$set:{"stats.*.BattackPlvl": 4}});
```

given how "human" can be anything else for each different documents

Thanks in advance